# Using Offset in Binomial/Logit GLM for Exposure Years?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, offset

I am building a GLM Model that predicts whether there will be a claim in a certain policy or not. So target variable is either 0 or 1, so my choice of GLM was Binomial, and link function was Logit.

In the data I also have an Exposure column, which has values greater than 0 but less than or equal to 1. 1 means that the policy has experience of 12 months, and 0.5 would mean that the policy has experience of 6 months.

How do i include this information in my GLM? Should I just use offset on exposure, or use log of exposure?

Please suggest.

Comment: Use the cloglog link and log(exposure) as offset as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/217773/77222

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25415/using-offset-in-binomial-model-to-account-for-increased-numbers-of-patients